# How much damage does an Enlarged Huge Gray Ooze deal with their pseudopod?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

The stat block for the [Huge Gray Ooze](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/huge-gray-ooze) indicates that on a hit its pseudopod deals:

> 6d6 acid damage plus 2d6 acid damage, or 12d6 acid damage while the ooze is enlarged.

Looking at the smaller gray ooze's stat block, it seems that the additional 2d6 damage is possibly an error. Furthermore, the [source material](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wdotmm/caverns-of-ooze#HugeGrayOoze) for the creature seems to indicate that the additional 2d6 is not intended either.

How much damage is the Huge Gray Ooze supposed to deal when it hits with their pseudopod? Is it effectively 8d6 acid or 6d6? What about when it uses the Enlarge feature on itself, which doubles the damage dice for the pseudopod?

Answer (score 5):

#### There’s probably some bludgeoning damage here.

After looking at all the stat blocks, I think Wizards really messed up here. The basic gray ooze statblock reads:

> **Pseudopod**. *Melee Weapon Attack*: +3 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. *Hit*: 4 (1d6 + 1) bludgeoning damage plus 7 (2d6) acid damage, and if the target is wearing nonmagical metal armor, its armor is partly corroded and takes a permanent and cumulative −1 penalty to the AC it offers. The armor is destroyed if the penalty reduces its AC to 10.

Extrapolating from here, the huge gray ooze attack should read:

> **Pseudopod**. *Melee Weapon Attack*: +7 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. *Hit*: 21 (6d6) bludgeoning damage plus 7 (2d6) acid damage, or 42 (12d6) bludgeoning damage while the ooze is enlarged. If the target is wearing nonmagical metal armor, its armor is partly corroded and takes a permanent and cumulative −1 penalty to the AC it offers. The armor is destroyed if the penalty reduces its AC to 10.

It seems this is the correct damage because *every other gray ooze has bludgeoning damage with an acid damage rider*. This includes the gray ooze, the psychic gray ooze, the sentient gray ooze, the reduced-threat gray ooze, and the White Maw. All of these gray oozes are bludgeoning plus acid damage, so the huge gray ooze in question probably should be too.

Comment: Would the 2d6 acid be doubled as well? So 12d6 bludgeoning and 4d6 acid?

Comment: @Pyrotechnical I dont think so.